# how to download modules to use with plpython postgresql

Tags: postgresql, plpython, postgresql-15, postgres-plpython

I'm trying to use plpython3u with postgresql on windows 11, and I want to use the `requests` library to make http requests..
So I did this test function:

```html
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION teste()
   RETURNS TEXT
AS $$
    import requests
    
    return '10'
$$ LANGUAGE plpython3u;
```

I can install the plpython3u extension successfully, this function is also created successfully, but when trying to select this function I receive this error:

```html
ERROR: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
  Onde: Traceback (most recent call last):
  PL/Python function "teste", line 2, in <module>
    import requests
função PL/Python "teste"
```

It's saying that my requests module is not available. postgresql I get this error, can anyone help me with how I can download the requests package to use in my plpython3u function?

I tried running pip3 install requests --force in this path: `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\15\pgAdmin 4\python`

and apparently the requests package was installed, but when trying to run the function I showed above, the same error persists.

for more context: I installed plpython3u using the edb stack builder/language packages (all the correct environment variables are installed, so much so that simple plpython functions run in my database, except the import request)

I ran the `pip3.exe install requests` command in my directory: `C:\edb\languagepack\v4\Python-3.11\Scripts`, and I received an error

```
Falha na execução do programa 'pip3.exe': O executável especificado não é um aplicativo válido para esta plataforma de
```

SO.No linha:1 caractere:1

- pip3 install requests
- 

No linha:1 caractere:1

- pip3 install requests
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed
  ```

Furthermore, I still cannot use the requests package in my plpython3u function because the error already mentioned at the beginning of the question occurs

Comment: Have you pip installed `requests` to the Python environment you are working in? In other words can you open the python or ipython CLI(outside Postgres) and import `requests`?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I can run the command pip3 install requests, and pip installs the request but it still generates the error

Comment: Yes but did you install it in the environment that the version of Python you are linked to in `plpython3u` is running in?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver yes, I did what you mentioned.. but nothing yet

Comment: Did what? Unless you provide an update to your question with details on your setup and a step by step account of what you did there is no way to provide an answer.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I ran the pip3.exe install requests command in my directory: C:\edb\languagepack\v4\Python-3.11\Scripts, and I received an error (Program 'pip3.exe' failed to execute)
I updated my question and put this information there